# HIghlight names in excel sheet if present in a second

Tags: excel-formula

I have a fairly large excel workbook with two sheets. The first sheet has peoples names formatted as such:

Last Name | First Name

The Second is a master sheet with with same format.

I am looking to have the names in sheet one highlighted if they are present anywhere in sheet 2.

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in conditional formatting,

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A,A1,Sheet2!$B:$B,B1)>0`

You need to use this formula under conditional formatting in `Sheet 1`